# Vue mounting and initialization timing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component that passes the reference to an internal element, to the parent via `defineExpose`. Here I log the element, in my real scenario I try to manipulate it.

[SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
// Comp.vue

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const el = ref(null);
defineExpose({ inner: el });
</script>

<template>
    <p ref="el">My Element</p>
</template>
```

```js
// App.vue

<script setup>
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const myRef = ref(null);

function logMe() {
  console.log(myRef.value);
}

onMounted(async () => {
  //await nextTick(); <-- This solves the problem
  logMe();
});
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logMe">Log the element</button>
  <Comp :ref="(el) => {myRef = el ? el.inner : undefined}" />
</template>
```

I learned that in Vue, child components are mounted before their parents, and in fact that's what happens, but if I try to access `myRef` once the parent is mounted, it's still `null`.

The solution to the problem is to wait for the next tick, but I don't understand **why** operations aren't completed when elements are mounted and why the next tick ensures that everything is completed, since these are internally asynchronous operations.

Comment: ref function runs more than once and accesses el.inner too early. You generally don't need one, it's for fine-grain control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM refs are only available :

- On mount for direct refs to children
- After the next tick for every other ref

You're relying on a child's DOM ref to populate your own, so you have to wait a tick to properly have access to the element and refs.

Comment: Can you "review" my implementation? Also, I realized that using `:ref="(el) => { myRef = el }"` I can access immediately `myRef.value.inner` without waiting for the next tick... is this a "direct ref" ?

Comment: A direct ref is `<el ref="myRef"/>`. I assume that `<el :ref="el => { myRef = el }"` is just treated as the same.

Comment: I'm assuming using the ref on the component works because you get a hold of the instance and don't need to process the changes to call the ref function again